# How can I expand an Ipv6 address step-by-step?

Tags: ipv6

Given this IPv6 address: ::ffff:10.0.1.15

How can I expand this?

I know that :: replaces a big string of zeros.

But what about the 10.01.15?

What does the dot even mean?

When using a converter on the internet I get 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:0A00:010F but I wasn't able to find a simple tutorial explaining how its done.

Comment: 10 -> 0A, 0 -> 00, 1 -> 01, 15 -> F

Answer (score 2):

`0A00:010F` means `0A.00.01.0F`, which is `10.0.1.15` in hexa -> decimal

Answer (score -1):

Going to the interal settings sir and configure the ip address setting to ip v 6. The host and client will change to the standard format.